# Resign First Responder on ScrollView Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

How can I hide the keyboard on ScrollView touch event...

Scenario is like that...

> ->View ->ScrollView ->Textfield

I  want to hide the keyboard on touch of scrollView. I tried to override the class for scrollview but still i can't do it.

Comment: I think you need to use a delegate.

Comment: Still Can somebody help me to solve this???

Answer (score 8):

Doing like this will help:

```
@interface MyClass <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
}

@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  yourScrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

If you really want to handle the touch event, then you need to subclass the UIScrollView and override the method:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view {

}
```

More about [UIScrollView touch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW12)

Comment: I need to make the keyoboard hide on touch not on dragging the ScrollView...so is there anybody who can help me with this!!!!

Comment: the ...willBeginDragging event is only fired when the finger is dragging, so it can't be used to respond to tapping.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me

in your viewController's viewDidLoad-method

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
    tapScroll.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [viewScroller addGestureRecognizer:tapScroll];
```

where viewScroller is your scroller. In the tapped-method we have

```
    - (void) tapped {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
```

Don't know why but the above did not work for me...even though it should

Comment: Yes, after having the Gestures in iOSSDK this is a nice solutions as answered by @Dax.But this question was asked along long back where there were no Gestures.But +1 from myside.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Add gesturerecognizer for scrollview,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
    tapScroll.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [yourScrollview addGestureRecognizer:tapScroll];
    [tapScroll release];
```

Resign your keyboard in (tapped:) method.

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at this answer, This is the easiest one I found.

[UitextField resignFirstResponder does not work in scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089845/uitextfield-resignfirstresponder-does-not-work-in-scroll-view/5090018#5090018)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
     return YES;
 }
```