# UitextField resignFirstResponder does not work in scroll view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitouch

I have 2 functions to resignFirstResponder but neither of them works when the textfields are in scrollview

my functions:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

        if (theTextField == textField1) {
        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    if (theTextField == textField2) {
        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    if (theTextField == textField3) {
        [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
    }


    return YES;

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
    [textField3 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

I have linked the scroll view in IB, I can not find out why it does not works there only when I click outside of scrollview.so it only responds to view, but why?I thougth that `[[event allTouches] anyObject]`    respond to ALLtouches at ANYObjects

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be a bit more elegant to add a transparent view that inherits `UIControl` with the size that equal to your scroll view to the very back of it and then just create `IBAction` for this new view?

Comment: You mean my view has scrollview and it has a transparent new view?

Comment: Assume you have your scrollview. You should add another `UIView` on it via Interface Builder. This view should completely resemble your scrollview frame and should lie lower than all your textfields. Then set it's class to `UIControl` and change your `touchesBegan` method to some `IBAction` method and the simply bound `touchUpInside` of that new view with this new method - see source code on http://iphonedevbook.com/, chapter 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a gesture recognizer to get the background tap. Use cancelsTouchesInView = NO to forward all other touches to the right receivers.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTappedBackground:)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Comment: can you give me the equivalent swift code? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *_currentTF;
}

@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    yourScrollView.delegate = self;
    yourTextField.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [_currentTF resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    _currentTF = textField;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: better to give some explanation for your answer