# How to resign first responder from a scroll view with touchesBegan?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

prior to adding a `scrollView` to my `view` the following

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}`

Worked great to dismiss the keyboard once the user touched anywhere on the screen. 
Now that have added my textfield(s) to a `scrollView` the code doesn't seem to work. I have tried calling it with:
`[_scrollView endEditing:YES];` but this does not work either.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue? I DO **NOT** want to do this by adding a clear button in the back of my `scrollView` to call my method. Thanks

EDIT:

Also tried implementing:

`- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [_emailTF resignFirstResponder];
}`

But did not get the result I was looking for

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3633268/1842694)

Comment: Yes, that method did not work for me

Comment: Add tap gesture on UIScrollView.

Comment: Thats what I specified I don't want to do @trick14

Comment: Then use `@property(nonatomic) BOOL delaysContentTouches;       // default is YES. if NO, we immediately call -touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` and 
`@property(nonatomic) BOOL canCancelContentTouches;    // default is YES. if NO, then once we start tracking, we don't try to drag if the touch moves`

Comment: Using tap gesture will be simpler though.

Comment: Does `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` ever get called? Maybe you didn't set the scroll view's delegate?